# How do you use more available cores when using DoParallel to tune models on tidymodel

Tags: r, r-caret, doparallel, tidymodels, r-ranger

I'm tuning some random forest models using ranger in tidymodels. I have a fairly large dataset with many columns. As a result, I set up a digital ocean droplet for tuning/trainng using instructions from [Danny Foster's article: R on Digital Ocean](https://www.dfoster.science/post/r-on-digital-ocean/). The system I'm using to train my models is running on Intel hardware and has 32 cores and 64gb of ram.

[image]

I use the following command before tuning to achieve parallel processing:

```
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores=28)
set.seed(345)

tune_res <- tune_grid(
  tune_wf,
  resamples = figs_folds,
  grid = 10
)
```

When I use the htop command to view processing on the system I see that 17 to 18 of the 32 cores are consistently being utilized.  This number seems consistent the DoParallel documentation that states 50% of the cores are utilized if cores are not specified. I figured 2 core are set aside for other duties and my model is using the 16.

Therefore it seems like something must be wrong with how I am specifying the number of cores to use.

```
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cores=28)
```

How should I specify the number of cores to use in DoParallel.

**EDIT UPDATE**:
When I switched from tuning a random forest model to training a logistic regression. All of the cores and much more of the available memory were utilized. Here is the htop image from the logistic regression model training:

[image]

As you can see all of the cores are utilized and approximately 46 GB of RAM.  Is this an indication that different models can utilize cores in different ways.

Comment: Do you have a gist or some other place to show the code? A lot depends on how you are doing things and the code here is a bit minimal.